# Perl NET::SFTP::FOREIGN execute remote perl script

Tags: perl, ssh, sftp

Is there any way to run a remote perl script using NET::SFTP::FOREIGN??

I know there are modules like SSH::EXPECT that would accomplish this, however I'm limited to very few modules that are pre-installed (I don't have permissions to install more).

Comment: SFTP is just a file transfer protocol. It does not allow remote command execution.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to support that from looking at [the docs on cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.75/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm) for it.   However you can

1. Use ssh commands via [Perl's system()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) or even [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.046/lib/IPC/Run3.pm) if you have that installed
2. see if you have a version of [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.60/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm) installed already which is by the same author.

I've used all these methods with success.